UK visit visa bank statement question
I am resident in GCC country, I will apply for UK tourist visit visa. I have current bank account which I receive the salary through it, and saving account under same bank under my name also, I transfer money between both accounts.
Is transfer between my current and saving account can be reason to reject the visa?

I have some difficulty to understand your question. Income and funds are mostly used to see if you can afford the travel and you will not do it to work illegally. Saving accounts should be ok. But it all depends on your situation, so it may be difficult to answer without being too generic.

Transferring your own money (eg from salary) between accounts in your own name is perfectly normal. Inter account transfers only raise a red flag if the source of the money is not evidenced. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

As detailed in another Q&A (UK Visa Refusal: Provenance of funds/parking), your overall financial position and where the funds come from are important to get a UK visa. Some transfers between a savings and a current account would be expected but if it looks like you are trying to obscure where the money comes from or you rely on savings to compensate a salary that's too low to afford your travel or your lifestyle then you may have a problem.

In addition to this answer: I'd just include proof for both accounts, then there's no question where that money is coming from and how much that account has, no questions if you're just receiving it from someone else but routing thru another account etc. (I've done this before)
